# Windows 7 - Run program when Recycle Bin Emptied

Tags: windows-7, trash

Is there a way to make a program run every time the Recycle Bin is emptied in windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a work around, you could easily do this with a bat file or similar.

So, run a script which first, empties the recycle bin

```
rmdir /q /s C:\Recycler
```

and then, start the program you want

```
start notepad
```

Save both of these to notepad, save as name.bat (note the bat) and when you run it, it will empty recycle bin and then open the program.

Comment: In Windows Vista and later the folder is called `$Recycle.Bin`.